# react redux middleware dispatch 2 actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware, react-redux

The first chunk as an action creator below works as is with thunk, but I want to also apply the 2nd chunk, which is a promise middleware. How do I tweak it so that it can dispatch 2 actions?

```
export const fetchPokemon = function (pokemonName) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: 'REQUESTING'})
    const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`
    return fetch(requestURL)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      dispatch(receivePokemon(formatPokemonData(data)))
      dispatch(fetchPokemonDescription(pokemonName))
    })
  }
}
```

middleware

```
const fetchPromiseMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (typeof action.then !== 'function') {
    return next(action)
  }
  return Promise.resolve(action).then(function (res) {
    if (res.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response from server")
    }
    return res.json()
  }).then(store.dispatch)
}
```

I've tried the below but get an error:

> store.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 ,
>   _actionCreators.receivePokemon) is not a function

```
const fetchPromiseMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (typeof action.then !== 'function') {
    return next(action)
  }
  return Promise.resolve(action).then(function (res) {
    if (res.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response from server")
    }
    return res.json()
  }).then(function (data) {
    return store.dispatch(receivePokemon(formatPokemonData(data)))
  }).then(function (data) {
    return store.dispatch(fetchPokemonDescription(data.name))
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your actions?

Answer (score 0):

there's not enough code in your question, but it seems when you call `receivePokemon(formatPokemonData(data))` in the code you show, `receivePokemon` isn't a function, now you need to check where is that defined, it probably isn't.